# Listing all categories on a single page and all pages that belong to a category within a jquery slider in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I really need some help. I've been banging my head since yesterday morning trying to build a custom design for my girlfriend's baking and cooking recipe blog in wordpress and I'm getting pretty frustrated at this point.
I followed the Lynda.com tutorial on making a custom design in wordpress and I managed to separate the template into header, main section and footer, but I kinda got stuck after that.
Here is a raw html page to see what the site should look like:
http://natalija.co.nf/index.html

And here is where I need some help. I want the main page to be divided into sections, each with a unique ID and data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" for parallax background effect. These sections would represent categories (cakes, cookies, drinks, dishes etc.). Each category should contain an article with it's own class and data-stellar-ratio="1.5". Within an article there would be an h1 tag with the category title and a jquery slider that would contain links to recipes from that category.
So the structure of a section should look like this:

```
<section id="teroteikolaci" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <article class="torteikolaci" data-stellar-ratio="1.5">
        <h1>TORTE I KOLAČI</h1>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="slider">
                <li class="slide">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="wp-content/themes/Natalija/images/torte-i-kolaci-thumb01.jpg" alt="random">
                        <div class="bubble">
                            <h5>Čoko mousse torta 1</h5>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="wp-content/themes/Natalija/images/torte-i-kolaci-thumb02.jpg" alt="random">
                        <div class="bubble">
                            <h5>Čoko mousse torta 2</h5>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="wp-content/themes/Natalija/images/torte-i-kolaci-thumb03.jpg" alt="random">
                        <div class="bubble">
                            <h5>Čoko mousse torta 3</h5>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

As I said, I managed to separate the template into header.php, footer.php and home.php,
however I only managed to place the raw html code into home.php which I would like to replace with dynamic content, but I got lost following the guy from the tutorial.
I don't want the categories to be separate pages. I want them all to be displayed within the home page. How do I accomplish this?
I'm new to wordpress so the dashboard kinda confuses me and I'm not familiar with the wordpress php functions so I would really appreciate if someone could give me some guidelines on how to pull this through.

edit:

```
        <?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        ?>

    <section id="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <article class="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" data-stellar-ratio="1.5">
            <h1><?php echo $category->name; ?></h1>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul class="slider">

        <?php
    }

    $args = array (
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category_name' => $category->slug,
        'nopaging' => true,
    );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
            $custom_query->the_post();

                // begin your slider loops in here
                ?>

                    <li class="slide">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            <div class="bubble">
                                <h5><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
    <?php }
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress fetches posts / pages using the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object (and the nice thing is that it's well documented and you have access to use it and customize it).  I would recommend that you create a dedicated loop (using WP_Query) for **each** section.  Let me show you how...

Using "TORTE I KOLAČI" as the first example, just before you begin that section you can create a *new* loop like so:

```
// WP_Query arguments allow you to filter out / sort which posts you want
// In this example, I'm just telling WordPress to give me ONLY posts under the 
// TORTE I KOLAČI category and NOT to use paging (so you get ALL posts in that 
// category without limits)
$args = array (
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'torte_i_kolaci',
    'nopaging' => true,
);

// The Query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Note: The `category_name` is actually the [slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Slug) of the category (and you can find that in the admin section under each category you've defined).

Now it's time to use the `$custom_query`.

Each section will still have the wrapper code like so:

```
<section id="teroteikolaci" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <article class="torteikolaci" data-stellar-ratio="1.5">
        <h1>TORTE I KOLAČI</h1>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="slider">
```

Except now you'll switch into PHP and utilize functions such as [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail), [`get_the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) and [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) like so:

```
<?php
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
        $custom_query->the_post();

            // begin your slider loops in here
            ?>

            <li class="slide">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <div class="bubble">
                        <h5><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h5>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

And now that you've looped all your posts, it's time to close out the wrapper...

```
            </ul>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Now you can repeat this pattern for each category you plan to list (SITNI KOLAČI, NAPICI, etc).

**Some Notes**

I've assumed that your posts are actually *posts* and not *pages* (for each item in the loop).  If you need pages, you can alter your `$args` array like so:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'torte_i_kolaci',
    'nopaging' => true,
);
```

Dig into the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) page on the codex to see how flexible these queries can be.

You might want to make your code even *more* dynamic and easy to maintain by **first** fetching your categories **and then** looping those to output the "outer wrapper".  WordPress has a function called [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) that I use all the time.  `get_categories` also has it's own `$args` array, so take a look at the docs to see what you can do with it. You would structure your code like so:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
    ?>

<section id="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <article class="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" data-stellar-ratio="1.5">
        <h1><?php echo $category->name; ?></h1>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="slider">

    <?php
}
```

And now the cool part!  You can drive all your inner loops (using WP_Query) from the `$category->slug` value like so...

```
$args = array (
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => $category->slug,
    'nopaging' => true,
);
```

**Putting It All Together**

So this is what the entire code snippet would look like (I added some comments for some of the braces that help you see where certain loops begin and end).

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
    ?>

    <section id="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <article class="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" data-stellar-ratio="1.5">
            <h1><?php echo $category->name; ?></h1>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul class="slider">

                <?php
                    $args = array (
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'category_name' => $category->slug,
                        'nopaging' => true,
                    );
                    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
                        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
                            $custom_query->the_post();

                                // begin your slider loops in here
                                ?>

                                    <li class="slide">
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                            <div class="bubble">
                                                <h5><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                    <?php } // end $custom_query loop

                    } else {
                        // no posts found
                    }

                    // reset the postdata
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
<?php
} // end $categories loop
?>
```

Hope this helps get you unstuck, have fun!

Comment: I tried making the code more dynamic as you recommended and I made an error somewhere so the page now loads category within a category. Can you please look at the code I used and tell me what did i do wrong?
I'll update the original post so you can see it.

Comment: @GoranTesic I think I see the problem. I wasn't 100% clear in my response, but the category loop should wrap *all* of your queries. I'll post a full code snippet of how everything fits together in my response at the end.

Comment: Thanks a million. Everything works fine and it looks a whole lot cleaner now.